# RoR: Using CRON and Actionmailer to send daily email updates to all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, actionmailer

What exactly would be the best way to go about using a cron task to send daily e-mails of updates to all users on my network? The e-mail would be made up of different information from multiple models.

I want to do something like "1 new friend requests : *name* ..." from the request model and user model and "There are 3 upcoming events from your friends: *event name* hosted by *name*..." from the event and user model.

I realize this is a common task but I didn't see much information on it, so any general tips about doing something like this would be greatly appreciated!

Side note: I will be using the Heroku daily cron plug-in to accomplish this if that matters (although I don't think it should).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually just write a rake task and add it to CRON.

The rake task will look like this:

```
namespace :notifications do
  desc "Sends notifications"
  task :send => :environment do
    MyModel.all_users_to_notify.each do |u|
      MyMailer.notification(u).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

And your crontab should look like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
HOME=/path/to/your/rails/app
PATH=/path/to/ruby/binaries

30 17 * * * rake notifications:send
```

Comment: I forgot  => :environment, and it won't work, can you explain me why? thanks so much!

Comment: You use the hash syntax to declare task dependencies. There's a task named `:environment`, which only purpose is to load the Rails environment. If you omit the `=> :environment` dependency, your task will work outside of your Rails environment, thus booting up faster and with a lower memory footprint. This could be useful sometimes, like deleting temp files etc.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is looking for this answer, I recommend using the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem for cron tasks.  This will keep you from having to write a rake task, as well as giving you a nicer cron syntax:

app/mailers/my_mailer.rb:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def my_email
    ...
  end
end
```

config/schedule.rb

```
job_type :runner, "cd :path && rvm 2.0.0 do bundle exec script/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"

every 1.days, at: "7:00 am", roles: [:app] do
  runner "MyMailer.my_email.deliver"
end
```